# Serialize form, where fields have multiple child fields

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one form which has 4 fields:

1. Full Name
2. Email
3. Text Area
4. Address

Full name and address have **multiple fields.**

I have 4 columns in the database: full name, e-mail, text area, and address.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve the result?

Here is the form layout:

[image: form layout]

Comment: You can either concatenate the subfields with javascript before you submit them, or you can change your web service to accept all of the different subfields, and process them there before storing in the database. Honestly your life will be easier if you just have the database match the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are constrained to the 4 fields in the database you can concatenate the 2 fields with a known delimiter like

Assuming

```
fname = $('#fname').val();
lname = $('#lname').val();
```

Then

```
delimiter = "~";
fullname = fname  + delimiter + lname;
```

And the same for address

Then when you read the fields into the form for an edit you can use a split on the delimiter to break them up

```
name = fullname.split(delimiter);
fname = name[0];
lname = name[1];
```

However a much better solution is to add more fields to your database table to accommodate the individual fields